# django catching multiple parameter in url

Tags: python, django, url

In one of my template I m doing this..

```
<form action="{% url "answer-submit" question.id %}" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="anstext"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Answer">     
</form>
```

Here I want to send the value of `question.id` and `anstext` to url...

my url is

```
url(r'^answer/(?P<anstext>\w+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/',AnswerSubmitView.as_view(), name="answer-submit"),
```

Now when I do this it says no reverse matching error.

Any idea ??

Here in this view I want to save these data in database..

```
class AnswerSubmitView(UpdateView):

    model = Answer

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.anstext = request.GET.get('anstext',False)
        print self.anstext
        return super(AnswerSubmitView, self).get(request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why should `anstext` go to the *URL*; it is a multi-line text area; the browser will send the value in the POST body instead.

Comment: In any case, you are generating the URL for the form before sending it to the browser; there is no value for `anstext` at that stage, so you cannot use it in the URL either.

Comment: `^answer/(?P<anstext>\w+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/` need 2 parameter `anstext` and `pk`, in url you are passing `question.id` which is i think `pk`. DJango didnt get url with one parameter so it gives reverse url not found error. As @MartijnPieters mention best option is use `anstext` as `POST` and change url to `^answer/(?P<pk>\d+)/'.

Comment: after submitting the answer I want to redirect it to another view and I want to save these values to database...  Can I get this anstext value in another view using get method ??